# How to center logo between navigation list items with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do you make a navigation with five links, with one of the links being an image (the logo) which needs to be centered?

My HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <span>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </span>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Posthusets logo i hvid format" class="nav-logo"></a></li>
    <span>
        <li><a href="#">TakeAway</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav>* {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>
        <a href="#">Restaurants</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </span>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50"></a>
  <span>
        <a href="#">TakeAway</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzdcqq34/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-grow on li elements

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

ul{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orzo8d2t/

(note that I removed span theree)

Comment: I don't see your fiddle btw.

Comment: Doesn't actually center, unless either sides are exactly the same width, e.g.https://jsfiddle.net/3jwygv0m/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still needing help, here's how I'd go about accomplishing this. This works better responsively because as the screen gets wider, the gaps in-between each navigation item does not increase, it stays consistent. (At mobile you can hide this menu and show your mobile menu).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img width="200px" src="images/logo.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TakeAway</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```